# не могу получить ответ от бота телеграм

Tags: python, telegram

```
     https://api.telegram.org/<bot-token>/getUpdates
```

вместо bot-token вставляю туда токен бота телеграм.
приходит ответ:
{"ok":false,"error_code":404,"description":"Not Found"}

токен рабочий. программа подключается. бот работает. а если пытаюсь постучаться через `https://api.telegram.org/<bot-token>/getUpdates`
ответа нет.
в чем может быть причина?

также к нему стучался `https://api.telegram.org/file/bot<token>/<file_path>`
в программе бот принимает файл и сохраняет его.
в первые разы, когда запускал программу, то файл сохранялся и был доступен на `https://api.telegram.org/file/bot<token>/<file_path>`, все скачивалось, а потом начал выдавать ошибку, что токен не тот, насколько я понял из прочитанного в гугле.

Comment: Не хотите использовать telebot или aiogram?

Comment: там все работает. мне интересно, в чем можем быть проблема, если я напрямую через браузер захожу.